# Something like Java annotations in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, annotations, metadata

I am looking for something like Java annotations (a way to mark a field or a method with metadata) in Objective c, but i can't find anything that is really a surrogate of this Java Feature.

Is there a way to achieve the same result of a Java annotation in Objective-C ?

Basically in the actual situation i'm trying to mark some fields in a class that i want to export with a serializer, i want to mark all fields in the class that have to be exported or serialized ...

Is there some other way to mark those fields ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are probably looking for : **ObjectiveCAnnotate**

Answer (score 2):

Officially, there is no java-like annotation support in Objective-C. But there is a possible workaround to achieve this goal. Use formatted comments as annotation, then write a parser to parse those comment annotations and save them as a file from which you can read the annotations at runtime.

I have implemented a project named ROAnnotation which use this method to provides runtime java-like key-value pairing annotation at class/method/property for Objective-C. I think that is what you need.

[ROAnnotation on GitHub](https://github.com/jibeex/ROAnnotation)

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to provide meta data about a class (and its instances) seems to be to provide a class method which returns the information.

In your case, an array with the names of the properties to serialize, for instance.